# Email view that does not show buttons and views of other activities

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I want to add Emails to navigation so It can be used like any other entity. Editing sitemap is not a problem but it does not work in the expected way.

First, of all it shows all entities, not emails only. And consequently there are filters for other activities which are unwanted.

How do I make email-view that does not show other activities?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Create a new view in CRM showing the records you wish to see
- Create a HTML web resource, with an iFrame pointing to the URL of the view you just created. It will look something like this `/advancedfind/advfind.aspx?AutoRun=true&QueryId=%7b495B7974-58AC-E234-92D4-EE155D107003%7d&ViewType=4230&etn=email`
- Point your sitemap to the new web resource

Comment: The trickiest part of this and the essence of my question is *how to get URL of that view*? I've tested URL you gave as an example with GUID of "Active Emails" view for our Organisation, but it did not work :(

Comment: After creating and saving your view, via Advanced Find, click the "Saved Views" button, place a tick next to the view you wish to use then click on "Copy a Link" button from the Ribbon. This will include the GUID of the view.

Comment: I did just that to get GUID of the view. But when I put that GUID into this url: `http://appserver/OrganisationCRM/advancedfind/advfind.aspx?AutoRun=true&QueryId=%7b495B7974-58AC-E234-92D4-EE155D107003%7d&ViewType=4230&etn=email` and try to open it I get an error :(

Comment: I've only tried this with custom views - are you trying to use native views?